# How to use Thread in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

When I run Python script I get error:

```
NameError: name 'Thread' is not defined
```

And error:

```
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'join'
```

This is my code:

```
 q = Queue()

    for i in range(num_worker_threads):
        t = Thread(target=worker)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

    for item in urls:
        q.put(item)

    q.join()
```

How to use Thread in Python 3?

Comment: I can assume that should be: `t =  threading.Thread(target=worker)`

Comment: This is not a [MCVE].

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: `t = threading.Thread(target=worker)` or `t = Thread(target=worker)` can both be right, depends on how you import. If you use the long option you only need `import threading` but if you use the short answer you need `from threading import Thread`, this is, importing the whole module threading for the first case and just the `Thread` class for the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the corresponding library:

```
from threading import Thread
```

Comment: But what is reason this: `AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'join'`

Comment: Which `Queue` object are you using? Write the import statement